# Как развернуть OpenDialog на весь экран?

Tags: delphi

У меня такой вопрос:

```
begin
    if OpenDialog1.Execute
    then ShellExecute(Handle, nil, PChar (OpenDialog1.FileName), nil, nil, SW_SHOW);
end;
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как сделать, чтобы OpenDialog1 открывался на весь экран (Delphi XE2 Win 7)...

Comment: Неужели нет вариантов кроме править самому Dialogs.pas (У меня Delphi XE2)

Comment: А что мешает вручную послать сообщение диалогу об изменении размеров? Только хэндл нужно знать по идее...

Answer (score 1):

Если неохото править что то самому, можно воспользоваться готовым решением. Установить [JEDI VCL for Delphi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/). Компонент который нас будет интересовать называется TJvOpenDialog. Устанавливаем у него св-во UseUserSize в True. Далее перед вызовом диалога разворачиваем его на весь экран.

```
...
JvOpenDialog1.Height:=Screen.Height;
JvOpenDialog1.Width:=Screen.Width;
JvOpenDialog1.Execute;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

ВСЕМ Спасибо, Вопрос снят. Отследил изменения реестра и нашёл, где сохраняется информация о состоянии окна OpenDialog.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\CIDSizeMRU
```

Может кому пригодится...

Answer (score 0):

Только править самому Dialogs.pas

Comment: Ну попробуйте найти альтернативные компоненты. Хотя поправить Dialogs.pas проще.

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё общесистемный FileBox eXtender - но его забросили и на 64-битной винде он плохо себя ведет :-(